# How to pre-create users with shared mail for password reset via Graph API

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

How is it possible to pre-create users programmatically (via Graph-API) and have a same mail address configured for them to be used along with the password reset user flow?

I figured that the signInNames mail or StrongAuthenticationUserDetails mail attribute are being used with the standard flow. BUT, signInNames are unique and StrongAuthenticationUserDetails (Authentication contact info: Email) is not editable via Graph API as of now.

Any idea how to accomplish the scenario above without developing our own password reset flow?

Comment: are you using custom policies or user flows?

Comment: Stefan, can you accept the answer if it works for you?

Answer (score 1):

I assume the scenario is creating user by invitation, where customer changes their password after first login.

Here is the sample for doing that
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/invite

**If you want to use the user flows,** 
You can create a user account as mentioned below, and then set the password reset user flow link to them. But then you will need to ask your customers to update profile as well, so that you know more about them.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet?tabs=applications#create-consumer-user-accounts

Comment: I was playing with builtin users flows, the answer does not cover the need of having a shared e-mail address for password reset purposes. E.g. have username based accounts like user1, user2, etc., and than have an shared mail attribute that is used for password resets (e.g. info@contoso.com)

Comment: So your scenario is to have one email for many user accounts?

Comment: Would be interested to know the use case. AFAIK there is no way to have a different email just for password reset and a different email for user name.

Comment: If username based login is enabled, B2C allows sign-up of testuser1 with info@contoso.com and testuser2 with info@contoso.com as well. I want to reproduce the same scenario but through Graph API. The users i want to create do not have their own email, but still want to enable password resets through e-mail. But I start to recognize that the approach might be the wrong.